# Using "despaired" as a replacement for "said" or "asked"

Tags: questions

May I say:

> "Why does this happen?" despaired Ralph.

Or if not, do you have any suggestions as to a suitable replacement for the placid "asked". What I'm looking for is a mixture of despaired and entreated.

Comment: to despair is to lose hope on something. How can asked be replaced by despair in every context?

Comment: No, just in this context :)

Comment: These substitutions are called [*said-bookisms*](http://www.dbjackson-author.com/blog/index.php/2012/01/25/writing-tips-said-bookisms-the-obscure-sin-that-can-doom-a-manuscript/).  In modern style, writers are often encouraged to stick to neutral tags like *said* and *asked*, or to leave them off altogether.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't seen *despair* used in such context anywhere.

As a verb, to ***despair*** means

> to *lose hope* or to *be without hope*.

Words which usually fill in the following blank:
"Why does this happen?"***_*__*_*** Ralph.
are *verbs* which depict a *verbal action* by the subject. For instance, *laughed, bawled, exclaimed, mumbled*. All these verbs depict a verbal action and hence fit. *Despair* doesn't fit the bill, I don't think it can be used here without sounding very odd, if not incorrect.

Perhaps you can say:
"Why does this happen?" moaned Ralph. (or groaned, sighed, cried - these all depict despair).